# How can I create a function that extract part of a txt using regular expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a group of txt with information of a computer, like this:

```
CPU
\tManufacturer\tIntel
\tModel\tPentium 4
\t\tDetails\tSocket LGA 3.00Ghz 2 cores
\t\tObservations\t...

RAM
\tSlot #1
\t\tType\tDDR2
\t\tSize\t1024 MBytes
\tSlot #2
\t\tType\tDDR2
\t\tSize\t1024 MBytes

Storage
\tHard drives
\t\tManufacturer\tMaxtor
\t\tSize\t500GB
```

- in fact the "\t" are "tabs"
- in some txt the order of the items and the details are diferents (2 cores socket LGA 3.00Ghz)

I already converted the txt to a String but I want to create a function in visual basic .net that extract the Manufacturer of CPU, Model, the socket, core speed and the number of cores, also the size of RAM 1 and 2 and the size of Hard drive

Comment: Have you already tried `String.Split` with `\t` as delimiter? If it's unsuccessful, try `CChar(vbTab)` as delimiter instead.

Comment: I have many txt and in some txt the information of the CPU can be below the RAM, so if I only split I could not know the position of the information I need, I thought I should use a regular expression, something like:
"tagname\t(.)\n". where "tagname" would be, for example, the model or the manufacturer.
But it does not work for me in all cases, for example when I want to get  the size of the RAM and hard disk or get the core speed

Comment: Seems like IndexOf and Substring would do what you need.

Comment: but look at "size", it repeats 3 times, if I want to get indexOf("size"), I only get the index of the first, and I have some txt with the information of the Storage before the RAM and some txt with the information of the storage after the RAM so I cant suppose that the first is the RAM

Comment: Then look for indexof RAM, substring starting at that point, then indexof Size within that, etc

Comment: I was going to suggest something like perterG's comment, but also get the index of "Storage".   If the `IndexOf("Size") > IndexOf("RAM")` but `< IndexOf("Storage")`, then you know it's in the RAM section.  Also, IndexOf has an overload that takes a starting index, so after you get the first Size for the RAM, keep checking using the previous offset + 1 as a starting point.

Comment: @dwilliss Ah I *thought* it had that overload, then couldn't locate it, for some reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following regex (PCRE) matches ram sizes:

```
(?:(.|\s)*?\n\nRAM|\n\n(.|\s)*)(*SKIP)(?!)|Size\\t\K.*
```

- `(*SKIP)(?!)` :

  - `(?!)` : fails
  - `(*SKIP)` : prevent backtracking
- `(.|\s)*?\n\nRAM` : matches everything from start until `\n\nRAM`
- `\n\n(.|\s)*` : matches everything after `\n\n`

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/N8bPc7/1/)

otherwise may be done in two steps

```
/RAM((?!\n\n).)*\n\n/gs
```

to retrieve RAM info, then

```
/(?<=Size\\t).*/g
```

to retrieve size inside RAM info

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent of "skip" in visual basic?

Comment: if control verbs are not supported, another option is to use `(?>(?:(?:.|\s)*?\n\nRAM|\n\n(?:.|\s)*))|((?<=Size\\t).*)` and to look only at group 1 matches